# Form submit issue: Cannot read property of undefined on form submit

Tags: keystonejs

I am new to keystonejs (using latest 4). Based on the [demo app contact form code](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-demo/blob/master/routes/views/contact.js), I created a form to add 2 dates. My issue is, on form submit I am getting a 500 error "Cannot read property 'bookedFrom' of undefined"... can you help me track this down? Thank you!

My code is:

> templates/views/booking.jade

```
extends ../layouts/default

block content
    form(method='post').form-horizontal
        input(type='hidden', name='action', value='booking.create')
        .form-group
            label.col-sm-2.text-left.control-label From
            .col-sm-10
                input(type='date' name='bookedFrom' value=formData.bookedFrom required placeholder="2018-01-01").form-control
        .form-group
            label.col-sm-2.control-label To
            .col-sm-10
                input(type='date' name='bookedTo' value=formData.bookedTo required placeholder="2018-12-31").form-control
        .form-group
        button(type='submit').btn.btn-primary Book
```

> routes/views/booking.js

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Booking = keystone.list('Booking');

exports = module.exports = function (req, res) {

    var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
    var locals = res.locals;

    // Set locals
    locals.section = 'booking';
    locals.formData = req.body || {};
    locals.validationErrors = {};
    locals.bookingSubmitted = false;

    view.on('post', { action: 'booking.create' }, function (next) {

        var newBooking = new Booking.model({
            bookedFrom: locals.FormData.bookedFrom,
            bookedTo: locals.FormData.bookedTo
        });
        var updater = newBooking.getUpdateHandler(req);

        updater.process(req.body, {
            fields: 'bookedFrom, bookedTo',
            flashErrors: true
        }, function (err,res) {
            if (err) {
                locals.validationErrors = err.errors;
            } else {
                locals.bookingSubmitted = true;
            }
            next();
        });
    });

    // Render the view
    view.render('booking');

};
```

> models/Booking.js

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var Booking = new keystone.List('Booking', { track: true });

/**
* Booking Model
* =============
*/

Booking.add({
    bookedFrom: { type: Types.Date, index: true },
    bookedTo: { type: Types.Date, index: true },
});

Booking.track = true;
Booking.defaultSort = '-createdAt';
Booking.defaultColumns = 'createdBy, bookedFrom, bookedTo';
Booking.register();
```

> routes/index.js

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var middleware = require('./middleware');
var importRoutes = keystone.importer(__dirname);

// Common Middleware
keystone.pre('routes', middleware.initLocals);
keystone.pre('render', middleware.flashMessages);

// Import Route Controllers
var routes = {
    views: importRoutes('./views'),
};

// Setup Route Bindings
exports = module.exports = function (app) {
    // Views
    app.get('/', routes.views.index);
    app.all('/booking', middleware.requireUser, routes.views.booking);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your variable names. You instantiate the `locals.formData` variable, but later refer to it as `locals.FormData`. The latter variable is undefined, resulting in your 500 error. Rename the variable that is being referred to in your model creation.

```
var newBooking = new Booking.model({
    bookedFrom: locals.formData.bookedFrom,
    bookedTo: locals.formData.bookedTo
});
```